# jquery.selectBox.js remove first option

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery.selecbox.js plugin and I need to remove the first option while dropdown menu is open. Here is my code

```
$('select').selectBox().focus(function () {
  $(this).find("option").eq(0).remove();
});
$("select").selectBox({
keepInViewport: false
});

<select id="numberOfRooms">
  <option value="0" >Please Choose</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: SO whats going wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$("select").selectBox({
    keepInViewport: false
});

$('select').focus(function () {
  $(this).find("option").eq(0).remove();
});


<select id="numberOfRooms">
  <option value="0" >Please Choose</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you have any idea wht it only works if I delete $("select").selectBox({ keepInViewport: false });

Comment: I've just figured it out focus doesn't work with jquery v1.10.2. That must be a bug inside jquery.selectBox